# Cuando ejecuto mi función retorna None aunque la variable tiene los valores

Tags: python, lista

Buen día. Espero se encuentre muy bien. =)

Mi problema es este:

```
def sortedSquares(nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    left = 0
    right = len(nums) -1
    square_array = []
    while (True):
            
        num1 = nums[left]
        square_array.append(num1*num1)

        num2 = nums[right]
        square_array.append(num2 * num2)

        left += 1
        right -= 1

        if nums[left] == nums[right]:
            middle = nums[left]
            square_array.append(middle*middle)
            break
    return square_array.sort()
```

**
Lo que debe hacer esta función es que cuando introduzco el argumento [-4,-1,0,3,10], esta multiplica cada valor con si mismo y los añade a la lista square_array, y luego retorno esta lista ordenada así [0,1,9,16,100].
**

Cuando ejecuto esta función con el argumento [-4,-1,0,3,10] paso por paso al final la variable square_array contiene la lista que deseo pero al retornarla me retorna None.

Si son tan amables, quisiera saber porque se produce esto. Yo ya debuggie paso por paso y todo correcto, hasta que me retorna None. =(

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Debes poner `square_array.sort()` y luego `return square_array`, porque `sort` no devuelve ningún valor, solo ordena la lista...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que el método `sort` de la lista trabaja con la misma lista y no devuelve una nueva. [Documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Hay dos opciones:

1. Utilizar `square_array.sort()` y luego retornar `square_array`.
2. Utilizar el método [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), que regresa una nueva lista.

Ejemplo con `sort`:

```
from typing import List

def sortedSquares(nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    left = 0
    right = len(nums) -1
    square_array = []
    while (True):
            
        num1 = nums[left]
        square_array.append(num1*num1)
        

        num2 = nums[right]
        square_array.append(num2 * num2)

        left += 1
        right -= 1

        if nums[left] == nums[right]:
            middle = nums[left]
            square_array.append(middle*middle)
            break
    square_array.sort()
    return square_array

print(sortedSquares([-4,-1,0,3,10]))
```

Esto imprime:

```
[0, 1, 9, 16, 100]
```

Ejemplo con `sorted`:

```
from typing import List

def sortedSquares(nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    left = 0
    right = len(nums) -1
    square_array = []
    while (True):
            
        num1 = nums[left]
        square_array.append(num1*num1)
        

        num2 = nums[right]
        square_array.append(num2 * num2)

        left += 1
        right -= 1

        if nums[left] == nums[right]:
            middle = nums[left]
            square_array.append(middle*middle)
            break

    return sorted(square_array)

print(sortedSquares([-4,-1,0,3,10]))
```

Esto imprime:

```
[0, 1, 9, 16, 100]
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Sr Heytale, ahora lo entiendo mucho mejor!

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El algoritmo anterior devuelve None porque la función sort() no devuelve nada; ordena la lista en su lugar. Para devolver la lista ordenada, simplemente elimina el método sort() de la última línea de la función:

```
square_array.sort()
return square_array
```

Ahora la función devuelve una lista ordenada de cuadrados.